# MyBatis, Spring, c3p0 and Maven Integration Tutorial

Tags: spring, maven, mybatis, c3p0

Does anyone knows a good *hello world* using **mybatis 3** + **spring 3** + **c3p0** with **maven**? I'm searching a lot of sites (including stackoverflow, of course) but all I get are tutorials for integration with Hibernate, or using dbcp instead of c3p0, but it's not what I want.

I'm pretty new on those frameworks, so a step-by-step would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same difficulty when I first started to learn Spring+Mybatis. It's suprising that we dont have enough tutorials on it.

I know you said you wanted a hello world application. Truly, speaking as an EE developer, even a hello world application isn't easy.

To understand the power of Spring and how it interacts with MyBatis, try this link:

- [Spring+MyBatis tutorial](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/java/setting-mybatis-in-spring/?lang=en)

Also, I would suggest watching videos on Spring at :

- [Spring- JavaBrains](http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/spring-framework.html)

You can also use

- [Spring tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/)

for a fuller understanding of Spring with code. Although the website **doesn't** cover MyBatis, I has a really good number of tutorials for Spring.

These resources got me started. It's a steep learning curve so good luck. :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your awnser! Your first tutorial and an example I've found on a running application with dbcp, helped me to successfully integrate MyBatis, Spring and c3p0.
Unfortunately I don't have enough points to reply my own question, because I would post the "step-by-step" what worked for me.
By the way, I'm really enjoying Mkyong's tutorials (your third link).